# How to post to different categories in wordpress using a custom php script

Tags: php, wordpress

i am developing a custom php script outside wordpress. The purpose of this script is to post to post articles on my wordpress blog.
I have almost achieve that put the only fuction remaining is that the post doesn't appear in any category or tag.
I have only been able to connect to the database and save data into the wp_posts table.
But i don't now how to go about accessing the database and make the post have a category and tag.

If you are wondering why am creating a custom php script for posting is that i added some functionality which i want during posting and made it lighter than the normal wordpress post-new.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all , You are not obliged to reinvent the wheel and do your own sql queries using MYSQLI or PDO , Or using anything else ,

All you need to do is just

Require wp-load.php file into your custom php script , Then you can use many wordpress builtin functions , After that just use the function

`wp_insert_post($args)`
 , in the args "array" include all the data you need regarding the post , Starting from the post author , post content , category , post excerpt and so on ..

Here is an example :

```
// Create post object
$my_post = array(
  'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['post_title'] ),
  'post_content'  => $_POST['post_content'],
  'post_status'   => 'publish',
  'post_author'   => 1,
  'post_category' => array( 8,39 )
);

// Insert the post into the database
wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

Check wordpress codex for more info :

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/

Comment: Thank you. But the only thing i don't understand yet is  how **  post_category => array( 8,39) ** workes

Comment: when post_category is array then the post will be set in the database under the two categories , But if you want it to link to one category only , Then you don't need to write array(x,y) just write 

post_category => x

Comment: If the worked for you please don't forget to make the question answered .

Comment: Thank you i really appreciate your effort.